# Find count of ids between a certain time range in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of ids logging in to a site in specific dates. 
I need to find how many times each id has logged in from the initial date of login until a year later.
Until now my query is:

```
select count(id), id, date 
from table 
where date >= (SELECT min(date) AS mindate from table) 
and date < (SELECT min(date) + interval '1 year' from table)
group by 2, 3
```

I am sure it is not right, because it returns count as 1 to all ids. 
Do you have any ideas?
Sorry, I am new to all these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strategy is to first compute the minimum date for *each* `id` group, and then join this back to the original table using the criteria you had in your original `WHERE` clause.  This effectively removes the records for *each* `id` group which are not in the range you want.  After this, a simple `GROUP BY` is all that is needed to get your result.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id)
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, MIN(date) AS mindate
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY id
) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date >= t2.mindate
    AND t1.date < t2.mindate + INTERVAL '1 year'
GROUP BY id
```

Note that I removed the `date` field from the `SELECT` list because it does not make any sense to include it there since it is not an aggregate (i.e. Postgres does not know *which* date you want to show for each `id` group).

Comment: no it's the same actually. I think that the problem is that it takes only the smallest date I have in my records and not the smallest date for each id.

Comment: though if i remove date, it indeed counts the number of ids, but still it returns the values from the first year only and not the values from the time they first logged on to a year after. When I query with min(date) and ids only I have the right outcome, but in the clause it has a different output.

Comment: @johnben I updated my answer.  You did not make your question very clear initially, and I would suggest that you work on this so that next time you get a better answer.

Comment: I am really sorry!! It was because there were two issues in my query. Just a comment, id in the outside query must be t2.id, otherwise I get error  that "id" is ambiguous, because it doesnt know which one to return. So if you want edit it, just in case anyone reads this in the future!

Comment: No worries...if you knew the exact answer already you wouldn't post :-)